# Unable to remove blanks/tabs from string

Tags: python, strip

I am using Python to build the logic. Facing the challenge in removing the whitespaces in the string.
Actual code as below:

```
searchExprLineWithoutSpace.replace(" ", "").strip())
```

Even i have triedwith lstrip, rstrip but no luck. Actual String in this is as below:

```
"// SetSearchExpr(searchExpr);
                ExecuteQuery();
                var FR = FirstRecord();"
```

Not matter what I do, I am unable to remove the space from the first line:
[image]

If someone can steer as to what else I can do, it would help. Thanks.

Comment: the string provided is not correct, did you want to you triple quote `"""` or `'''`? double quote does not work with multiline

Comment: share the actual code that you are using. (No images please)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Actual Code is as below:

Comment: "Actual Code is as below:" -- where? Update the post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all whitespace, you can use the generic paramter for `str.split`, then join it.

One thing I will note is that this string that you provided is incorrect, since it needs to be triple quote for multilines.

Anyways, if you want to remove the whitespace, you can do

```py
white_space_to_remove = "hello       world this    is uneven    whitespace"
white_space_to_remove = ''.join(white_space_to_remove.split())
```

This will give the string with no whitespace whatsoever, since the delimiter for str.join is just an empty string.

However, I'm unsure as to what you're trying to do with removing whitespace since your question was quite generic.

Note:
str.split without any parameters will by default split by any whitespace.